# Copying data by indexing the output dataframe by the input dataframe's value

Tags: r, text-processing

I have a csv file that I have read into a dataframe (basically an output of topics from MALLET's topics modeling features) that looks like this:

[image]

The function dput gives it in the form:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("file:/C:/mallet/my-data/dickens-greatexpectations.txt", 
"file:/C:/mallet/my-data/dickens-olivertwist.txt", "file:/C:/mallet/my-data/emma-austen.txt", 
"file:/C:/mallet/my-data/hardy-judetheobscure.txt", "file:/C:/mallet/my-data/hardy-pairofblueyes.txt", 
"file:/C:/mallet/my-data/jacob-room-woolf.txt", "file:/C:/mallet/my-data/melville-moby-dick.txt", 
"file:/C:/mallet/my-data/pride-and-prejudice.txt", "file:/C:/mallet/my-data/shakespeare-asyoulikieit.txt", 
"file:/C:/mallet/my-data/shakespeare-hamlet.txt"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(9L, 11L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 19L, 18L, 14L, 1L), V3 = c(0.239748159, 
    0.309737525, 0.346177616, 0.255417865, 0.247361424, 0.363149847, 
    0.244273675, 0.359370464, 0.623336798, 0.529540077), V4 = c(8L, 
    2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 15L, 1L, 14L), V5 = c(0.153314326, 
    0.180447378, 0.216411342, 0.222792466, 0.204428308, 0.106517068, 
    0.142443012, 0.225841963, 0.060758836, 0.10636646), V6 = c(12L, 
    8L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 3L), V7 = c(0.133753069, 
    0.119245504, 0.189293205, 0.115636944, 0.125618736, 0.100731465, 
    0.1118036, 0.214664183, 0.058264033, 0.081965395), V8 = c(2L, 
    12L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 17L, 16L, 3L, 12L), V9 = c(0.126641324, 
    0.106343402, 0.152679976, 0.114001734, 0.092237676, 0.097094801, 
    0.111000484, 0.116048098, 0.055665281, 0.069469092), V10 = c(13L, 
    15L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 15L), V11 = c(0.102613447, 
    0.088533751, 0.035143082, 0.072097009, 0.087287789, 0.081762956, 
    0.089448381, 0.040344043, 0.048284823, 0.046398994), V12 = c(15L, 
    17L, 4L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 4L, 15L, 8L), V13 = c(0.089197751, 
    0.061352267, 0.022595325, 0.060847551, 0.067365514, 0.067877511, 
    0.069480505, 0.01936756, 0.04454262, 0.035159716), V14 = c(16L, 
    4L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 16L, 17L), V15 = c(0.045022571, 
    0.043479293, 0.018194247, 0.044751566, 0.05556351, 0.06275312, 
    0.051052852, 0.012810897, 0.032276507, 0.029392192), V16 = c(17L, 
    16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 3L, 17L, 16L), V17 = c(0.040017423, 
    0.036038817, 0.005084651, 0.034467473, 0.04232972, 0.037379122, 
    0.043670789, 0.003133166, 0.025935551, 0.025842946), V18 = c(4L, 
    13L, 18L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 17L, 2L, 2L), V19 = c(0.030276392, 
    0.033395073, 0.004279347, 0.032379132, 0.02829822, 0.024568146, 
    0.042713651, 0.002576696, 0.018035343, 0.021258503), V20 = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 4L), V21 = c(0.014817455, 
    0.010440413, 0.003942243, 0.016755979, 0.014287175, 0.020600876, 
    0.039325163, 0.001657312, 0.010343035, 0.019631766), V22 = c(6L, 
    6L, 13L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 16L, 0L, 13L, 13L), V23 = c(0.011443732, 
    0.006704344, 0.002256723, 0.007614563, 0.010114543, 0.016385652, 
    0.034396453, 0.001657312, 0.009303534, 0.014603668)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", 
"V21", "V22", "V23"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

what this shows is name of the text and corresponding topic number and its associated percentage presence in the text, so in row1, col1 has text name, col2 has topic 9 and col 3 has topic 9's percentage, then col4 has topic 8 and then topic 8's percentage and so on. The topics are arranged in no particular order. So what I want to do is create a new dataframe which has this data arranged in the form where rows indicate text numbers, and col numbers indicate topic numbers, so row1 X col1 would have topic 1's percentage presence in text 1 and so on (NA if not present). The code I have is a simple nested loop:

```
topics <-read.csv("topics.csv", sep = ",", na.strings=c(""," ","NA"), header = FALSE)
row <- nrow(topics)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 21, nrow = row)) #initialize an empty dataframe of fixed size

for (i in 1:nrow(topics)) {
  for (j in 2:22) {
  df[i,topics[i,j] + 1] <- topics[i,j+1]

}


}
```

What I do over here is access the particular index of the new dataframe's column that corresponds with the topic and put the associated value of to
But the output that it gives is of the form:

[image]

dput's output:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(6, 6, 13, 10, 6, 6, 16, 0.001657312, 13, 
13), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.060758836, 0.529540077
), X3 = c(0.126641324, 0.180447378, 0.035143082, 0.115636944, 
0.125618736, 0.106517068, 0.051052852, 0.040344043, 0.018035343, 
0.021258503), X4 = c(0.014817455, 0.010440413, 0.003942243, 0.032379132, 
0.02829822, 0.06275312, 0.1118036, 0.003133166, 0.055665281, 
0.081965395), X5 = c(0.030276392, 0.043479293, 0.022595325, 0.072097009, 
0.087287789, 0.024568146, 0.089448381, 0.01936756, 0.010343035, 
0.019631766), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.255417865, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), X7 = c(0.011443732, 0.006704344, NA, NA, 0.010114543, 
0.016385652, 0.142443012, NA, NA, NA), X8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.363149847, NA, NA, NA, NA), X9 = c(0.153314326, 0.119245504, 
0.216411342, 0.222792466, 0.204428308, 0.081762956, 0.039325163, 
0.214664183, 0.048284823, 0.035159716), X10 = c(0.239748159, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X11 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.007614563, 
0.247361424, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X12 = c(NA, 0.309737525, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X13 = c(0.133753069, 0.106343402, 
0.018194247, 0.114001734, 0.092237676, 0.097094801, 0.069480505, 
0.012810897, 0.058264033, 0.069469092), X14 = c(0.102613447, 
0.033395073, 0.002256723, 0.016755979, 0.014287175, 0.037379122, 
0.042713651, 0.001657312, 0.009303534, 0.014603668), X15 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.623336798, 0.10636646), X16 = c(0.089197751, 
0.088533751, 0.189293205, 0.060847551, 0.067365514, 0.020600876, 
0.043670789, 0.225841963, 0.04454262, 0.046398994), X17 = c(0.045022571, 
0.036038817, 0.152679976, 0.044751566, 0.05556351, 0.067877511, 
0.034396453, 0.116048098, 0.032276507, 0.025842946), X18 = c(0.040017423, 
0.061352267, 0.005084651, 0.034467473, 0.04232972, 0.100731465, 
0.111000484, 0.002576696, 0.025935551, 0.029392192), X19 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.004279347, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.359370464, NA, NA), X20 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.244273675, NA, NA, NA), X21 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", 
"X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", 
"X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem with this is that in column 1 where topic 0's occurence should be there is a dummy value. In the first row of the original input dataframe of topics there is no corresponding entry for topic 0, therefore in the new dataframe's index of [1,0+1] there should be NA instead of the value of 6.000.
Similarly in row 3 topic 0 has some corresponding value which is not appearing in the output matrix. Could anyone help with this? Also is there a way I could do something like this without loops.

Comment: Please use `dput` or paste few lines of your data rather than posting an image file.

Comment: @akrun just did, sorry for it being a bit messy.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand how you got the `output` data from the original data

Comment: Basically, if the input first row is of the form text 1 9 0.35 6 0.20, then what I do is index into the 10th column and first row of the new dataframe and put 0.35 there, similarly in the 7th column, I put 0.20.

Comment: I add plus one because in the input file there is also a topic 0, so topic 0 corresponds with the column 1 of the output file. So, in the outer loop, I traverse through the rows, and in the inner loop, I traverse through the columns of each row, so the line ' df[i,topics[i,j] + 1] <- topics[i,j+1]' indexes into the corresponding column of the output dataframe, so if its topic 9 as in the above example, it will index into df[10] and put 0.35 there which is whats present in topics[i, j+1] (Sorry, hit enter prematurely)

Comment: Or thats what it should do. But its not doing this for column 1 where topic 0's values should be. For the rest of the columns it seems to be working fine. If you magnify the image a bit, it might become clear how the output is appearing.

Comment: Can you check whether the Output is correct as the 1st column in the Output seems to be not matching with the one that I got with indexing

Comment: Also, I think the last column (all NAs) is not needed

Comment: Yes, the output that I am getting is the same one that I posted above (I just ran the code again). I know its not correct for column 1 (by which I mean that according to the input data only rows 3,5 and 8 should have values of 0.346178, 0.247361 and 0.001657 in column 1 and the rest should be NA), which is where the problem seems to be, could you please paste what you are getting?

Comment: Could you run my code.  I get the same output as your output except for the first column and the last extra NA column

Comment: Is df1 in the code same as df? I am trying to run it with df1 replaced by df but its giving the error: 'Error in matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = max(indx1[, 2])) : invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)'

Comment: Yes, `df1` is the object name for the `dput` output  of initial data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a row/column index ('indx1') based on the topic number columns which are the alternating columns in the dataset.  These columns can be selected using a logical index ('indx') after removing the first column ie. the name of the text).  Create a `matrix` of NA with dimensions as the `nrow` of 'df1', and `ncol` as maximum value of the column index of 'indx1'.  Convert it to `data.frame`, and replace the NA values using the 'indx1'.

```
indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
df1[-1][indx] <- df1[-1][indx]+1
indx1 <- cbind(1:nrow(df1),unlist(df1[-1][indx]))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(df1),ncol=max(indx1[,2])))
df2[indx1] <- unlist(df1[-1][!indx])
head(df2,2)
#  V1 V2        V3         V4         V5 V6          V7 V8        V9       V10
#1 NA NA 0.1266413 0.01481746 0.03027639 NA 0.011443732 NA 0.1533143 0.2397482
#2 NA NA 0.1804474 0.01044041 0.04347929 NA 0.006704344 NA 0.1192455        NA
# V11       V12       V13        V14 V15        V16        V17        V18 V19
#1  NA        NA 0.1337531 0.10261345  NA 0.08919775 0.04502257 0.04001742  NA
#2  NA 0.3097375 0.1063434 0.03339507  NA 0.08853375 0.03603882 0.06135227  NA
#  V20
#1  NA
#2  NA
```

The output from OP's data

```
head(Out,2)
#  X1 X2        X3         X4         X5 X6          X7 X8        X9       X10
# 1  6 NA 0.1266413 0.01481746 0.03027639 NA 0.011443732 NA 0.1533143 0.2397482
# 2  6 NA 0.1804474 0.01044041 0.04347929 NA 0.006704344 NA 0.1192455        NA
#  X11       X12       X13        X14 X15        X16        X17        X18 X19
#1  NA        NA 0.1337531 0.10261345  NA 0.08919775 0.04502257 0.04001742  NA
#2  NA 0.3097375 0.1063434 0.03339507  NA 0.08853375 0.03603882 0.06135227  NA
#  X20 X21
#1  NA  NA
#2  NA  NA
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, thank you very much! I am having trouble understanding it a bit (very new to R), lemme run it out for a moment.

Comment: @QPTR I would suggest to split the code into parts and check the output for each segment, which will make it easier to understand

Comment: I think I got it mostly, but could you please explain what does the `!indx` in `df2[indx1] <- unlist(df1[-1][!indx])` do?

Comment: @QPTR `indx1` is the row/column index.  By doing `df2[indx1]` we are extracting the row/column elements of `df2` corresponding and replace that with the vector `unlist(df[-1][!indx1])`  Using `!indx` we are changing `c(TRUE, FALSE)` to `c(FALSE, TRUE)`.  So instead of getting the topic numbers we get the topic percentage columns that are alternating.